# Importing data from Azure SQL Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, azure-sql-database

Are there any guidelines or docs on importing data from a sql server database?  We are thinking about moving from Azure Sql Database to Firebase, we have about 2 gigs of data that we'd need to import.  We'd want to denormalise the data during the export/import process.

Comment: To export out - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export. Not sure about ingestion to Firebase.

Comment: This question is pretty broad; Firebase is a NoSQL database that imports JSON structures. Unless you can export into JSON, you're going to need to craft some code to manipulate your data into that structure for importing. Also, keep in mind there are no tables in Firebase and no Join clauses so you will need to think through how you are going to access that data in Firebase. Have you tried a small set of data to see how it would work?

Comment: We might be able to use this tool [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-import-data) to export the data in what ever JSON structure we want and import it into Firebase.